# Why will objects now be created from my class

Tags: java

An error points to the word "new" when I try to compile this program. I'm trying to create 2 objects from the carOrder class and I'm havin troubles! I've had this problem with other programs before and I'm not sure why and it's killing me, please help!

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarOrder
private String buyer;
private String carType;
private double cost;
private int quantity;
private boolean taxStatus;
private double discountedCost;
private double taxAmount;

// Default Constructor
public void carOrder()
{
}

// Constructor
public void CarOrder(String buy, String car, double cos, int quan, boolean tax)
{
    buyer = buy;
    carType = car;
    cost = cos;
    quantity = quan;
    taxStatus = tax;
}

// Sets the company buying cars
public void setBuyer(String buy)
{
    buyer = buy;
}

// Sets the car type being purchased
public void setCarType(String car)
{
    carType = car;
}

// Sets cost of the cars being purchased
public void setCost(double cos)
{
    cost = cos;
}

// Sets the quantity of cars being purchased
public void setQuantity(int quan)
{
    quantity = quan;
}

// Sets tax status for the cars
public void setTaxStatus(boolean tax)
{
    taxStatus = tax;
}

// Returns name of buyer to user
public String getBuyer()
{
    return buyer;
}

// Returns type of car to user
public String getCarType()
{
    return carType;
}

// Returns cost to user
public double getCost()
{
    return cost;
}

// Returns quantity of cars to user
public int getQuantity()
{
    return quantity;
}

// Returns tax status to user
public boolean getTaxStatus()
{
    return taxStatus;
}

// Returns discounted cost to user
public double getDiscountedCost()
{
    if (quantity > 10)
        if (quantity > 20)
            discountedCost = cost - cost * .10;
        else
            discountedCost = cost - cost * .05;
    else
        discountedCost = cost;

    return discountedCost; 
}

// Returns tax amount to users
public double getTaxAmount()
{
    taxAmount = cost * .0625;
    return taxAmount;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    CarOrder speedy = new CarOrder("Speedy Rental", "Mini Cooper", 22150, 15, true);
    CarOrder zip = new CarOrder("Zip Car Co.", "Ford Fusion", 27495, 6, true);

    System.out.println("Enter first Buyer");
    String buyer1 = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

}

Comment: Constructors don't have a return type. (void)

Comment: // Default Constructor
public void carOrder() is not a constructor

Answer (score 6):

```
public void CarOrder(String buy, String car, double cos, int quan, boolean tax)
{
```

should be

```
public CarOrder(String buy, String car, double cos, int quan, boolean tax)
{
```

> Constructor's don't have a return type, not even void.

Currently, you have a method named `CarOrder` in your class as it has a return type as void, which voilates the rules of custructor. If you remove void, then it'd a constructor as it has the same name as your class.

Same applies to your constructor with no-argsaswell.

```
public void CarOrder()
```

should be

```
public  CarOrder()
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a "{" right after public class CarOrder ... :)

Answer (score 0):

When you don't declare a constructor, Java provides a default constructor that have no arguments. As you declared `CarOrder(String buy, String car, double cos, int quan, boolean tax)`, the default constructor is not created anymore. You made a method called `carOrder`, that probably was an attempt to make a constructor with no arguments, but it has two problems:

- it has a return type (void) and constructor doesn't have one
- the name is different from the class (cardOrder isn't the same as CarOrder, since Java is case sensitive)

If you want to make a `new CarOrder()` call, just add the following code:

```
public CarOrder() {
    //insert your implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor with a return type is treated as a method by the compiler.